# Improvement for this SQL Cursor - It's really slow!

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, cursor

I have a sql procedure in which I use a cursor, but it's really really slow. I'm looking to improve the speed by using set-based operation or such things, but I've no idea how to apply it to this specific procedure:

```
    declare @isMulti bit
    declare @QuestionID int
    declare db_cursor cursor FAST_FORWARD for
        select distinct QuestionID
        from tblQuestions (nolock)
        where ID=@ID

    open db_cursor   
    fetch next from db_cursor into @QuestionID   

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    begin   
               --check if @isMulti is true or not for the current question
               if(@isMulti=1)
               begin
                    update tblAnswers
                    set col1 = 1, col2 = 1, col3 = (select count(*) from tblAnswers where QuestionID=@QuestionID and ID=@ID)
               end
               else if(@isMulti=0)
               begin
                    update tblAnswers
                    set col1 = AnswerID, col2 = 1, col3 = (select LEN(count(*)) from tblAnswers where QuestionID=@QuestionID and ID=@ID)
               end

               fetch next from db_cursor into @QuestionID   
    end
close db_cursor   
deallocate db_cursor
```

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: What are you trying todo with this procedure? Maybe a single update query may suffice.

Comment: I'm checking if a question is multi or not, and then updating that questions answers based on that information. The question table doesnt contain a column specifying whether it is multi or not, I have to call a function on the current question id in the cursor to check.

Comment: What is the deference between the updates when multi or not?

Comment: As shown, if the question is multi set the col1, col2, and col3 of answers in the range to certain value. col1 = 1 or answerid, col2 =1, col3 = count(*) or len(count(*))

Comment: You never populate `@isMulti`

Comment: Yes, the logic is left out and placed with comment --check if @isMulti is true or not for the current question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ted, I believe the cause of the slowness may be, beside the fact you are using a cursor, that the complete  tblAnswers is updated every time through the cursor.  I am expecting there are multiple rows in the answer table because a cursor was used during the design.  Until the decision is made on the changing from a cursor to a set-based op would you consider adding a WHERE clause to the update for the answer table.

On to my answser

If the udf is expensive then I would add a column to the questions table or create a new table if modifing the question table is not possible.  Populate the new column with a flag for "multi", with the result of the function, using a trigger when the question is inserted or updated.
Update the answers table in a sp using the code below as a model.  Call the SP with the question ID and the value of the "multi" flag.

```
update tblAnswers
set col2 =1,
col1 = CASE @isMulti THEN 1 Else AnswerID
col3 = CASE @isMulti THEN (select count(*) from tblAnswers where ID=@ID) ELSE (select LEN(count(*)) from tblAnswers where ID=@ID)
from tblQuestions
inner join tblAnswers on tblQuestions.QuestionID= tblAnswers.QuestionID
WHERE tblQuestions.QuestionID= @ID
```

Comment: ^_^ Thanks. It took me hours to realize this.
My procedure is a lot (1:13 seconds) faster - running at <5 seconds, although I believe using another method could reduce the total time to <1 second.
I'll mark this as the answer anyway, because it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but why doesn't this bit work outside the cursor if you take out the @QuestionId from the where clause?:

```
       --check if @isMulti is true or not
       if(@isMulti=1)
       begin
            update tblAnswers
            set col1 = 1, col2 = 1, col3 = (select count(*) from tblAnswers where ID=@ID)
       end
       else if(@isMulti=0)
       begin
            update tblAnswers
            set col1 = AnswerID, col2 = 1, col3 = (select LEN(count(*)) from tblAnswers where ID=@ID)
       end
```

**EDIT**

Without knowing more about the metadata I'm not sure about how to process the multi element to the questions, but this should be a good way to the answer:

```
declare @question table (questionid int, multi int)
declare @answer table (answerid int, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)

insert into @question (questionid, multi) values (1, 0)
insert into @question (questionid, multi) values (2, 0)
insert into @question (questionid, multi) values (3, 0)
insert into @question (questionid, multi) values (4, 1)
insert into @question (questionid, multi) values (5, 1)


insert into @answer (answerid, col1, col2, col3) values (1, 0, 0, 0)
insert into @answer (answerid, col1, col2, col3) values (1, 0, 0, 0)
insert into @answer (answerid, col1, col2, col3) values (2, 0, 0, 0)
insert into @answer (answerid, col1, col2, col3) values (2, 0, 0, 0)
insert into @answer (answerid, col1, col2, col3) values (3, 0, 0, 0)
insert into @answer (answerid, col1, col2, col3) values (4, 0, 0, 0)
insert into @answer (answerid, col1, col2, col3) values (4, 0, 0, 0)
insert into @answer (answerid, col1, col2, col3) values (4, 0, 0, 0)
insert into @answer (answerid, col1, col2, col3) values (5, 0, 0, 0)

update @answer 
set col1 = 1, col2 = 1, col3 = (select count(*) from @answer a join @question q on a.answerid = q.questionid where q.multi = 0 and [@answer].answerid = a.answerid)

select distinct * from @answer
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer - for each questionID I have to check if that question is multi or not, thus the cursor to loop through each question to check before checking that questions answers.

Comment: @Ted Mosbey - I've worked on it without really knowing your data, but it should give you a good pointer

Comment: Thanks, although - based on the multi value(which is calculated in a UDF) the col3 differs. 
If mulit col3 = select count(*)
else col3 = select len(count(*))

Answer (score 0):

You can update the answer table across a join, i.e join Answers to Questions on the ID and then restrict on the @ID using a where clause.

Comment: That doesn't give me the ability to update a value in the answer table based on some computation in the question table. If @mulit=1 do answer.col3=x, else answer.col3=y.
It's not based on questionID, rather the questionID is needed to calculate isMulti of that question.